# realtime visual insertion sort has gaps and output is delayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, dom

Okay so i'm relatively new to JS but have plenty of experience with python and java.

I have 2 questions with my code that I need assistance with. First here's an explanation and background of my code.

Ideally I want the simplest structured visual sort program that i can use as a base going forward with my coding progression to reference. I started by maximizing a container div which is used to populate with an x amount of divs .bars, the width and placement of the divs is handled automatically by flexbox as they are inserted. The height of each added div is generated randomly and stored within each individual elements attributes. I have all that done, easy. Then i made a element swapper function that swaps an elements position within thew DOM, that works perfect. Now for my questions. I would like to see the elements being sorted in real time as the for loops iterate but instead they are not updated until the loops end. And also My Insertion algorithm which i cannot find any errors in is not working properly but I dont think my approach in how it functions is wrong. Any help would be extremely appreciated. It should be very very easy to figure out for someone else.

```js
const sortDisplay = document.getElementById('sortDisplay');
let resetbtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
resetbtn.addEventListener('click', reset);

let count = 0;
let amount = 100;

// create div that has custom attribute value, unique style tag, default bar style and append.
function generateBar() {
  // generate div
  let bar = document.createElement('div');
  // keep track of the total amount of bars
  count++;
  // assign random number 0-100 and setAttribute to the div
  let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  // create custom attribute that holds its value
  bar.setAttribute('value', temp);
  // create unique style tag with height as a percentage based on Attribute
  let barHeight = document.createElement('style');
  barHeight.innerHTML = `.barHeight${count} {height: ${temp}%;}`;
  // add that unique style to the DOM
  sortDisplay.appendChild(barHeight);
  // now add that unique style to the div
  bar.classList.add(`barHeight${count}`);
  // use standard style from css as well
  bar.classList.add('sortBar');
  // now add that div to the DOM
  sortDisplay.appendChild(bar);
}

// clear container div and regenerate
function reset() {
  // clear all data within the container
  sortDisplay.innerHTML = '';
  // reset the count
  count = 0;
  // generate k bars
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    generateBar();
  }
}

// when page is loaded reset
reset(amount);

// swap elements within the DOM
function swapElements(obj1, obj2) {
  // create marker element and insert it above where obj1 is
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  obj1.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, obj1);
  // move obj1 to right before obj2
  obj2.parentNode.insertBefore(obj1, obj2);
  // move obj2 to right before where obj1 used to be
  temp.parentNode.insertBefore(obj2, temp);
  // remove temporary marker node
  temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
}

// sort the divs within the DOM
function sort() {
  for (let i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
    let j = i;
    for (j; j > 0; j--) {
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j].getAttribute('value') < document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j-1].getAttribute('value')) {
        swapElements(document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j], document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j-1]);
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Button to run the sort function
button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('click', sort);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sortDisplay {
  background-color: #305c50;
  background-image: linear-gradient(28deg, #305c50 0%, #6ab19e 70%, #82d8a6 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 25px;
}

.btn-container button {
  padding: 25px;
}

.sortBar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #0007;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="reset">reset</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>

<div id="sortDisplay"class="sortDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is very minor: you are comparing strings, and not numbers in your sort. Add a number conversion:

`if (+document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j].getAttribute('value') < +document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j-1].getAttribute('value')) {`

As strings, e.g. `"3" > "29"`.

The visualization isn't "visible real time", because the code finishes really really fast, and also without ever relieving control and waiting for a DOM-rerender. There are some minor issues with forcing DOM to re-render, but i don't think it's of much importance here.

To fix this, add a delay into the loops, this is very simple, all you need is a canonical delay function (`const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));`), an `async` in front of your `sort` (`async function sort`), and the appropriate delay between swaps (`await delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_SWAPS);`, 25ms currently. The exact time is not guaranteed, it may take e.g. 22ms once, and 27ms the next time, due to a variety of factors, but that's not too important).

However, this causes issues with cancellation: it's now possible, to reset, while the sorting is still going on (the dilemma of asnychronicity). Therefore, it's necessary to check, whether the current sorting has been cancelled, or not. Therefore a cancellation token for each sort process is required, which can be used to stop the old sort, when pressing reset. Last but least, starting a new sort (just pressing "button"), automatically cancels the last sort as well.

Note, that i am showing some concepts, but not necessarily code that would win beauty awards. I am also not changing anything that "works but I wouldn't do that way" - e.g. i'd prefer a canvas over doing an animation with tons of DOM-updates.

Working version:

```js
const sortDisplay = document.getElementById('sortDisplay');
let resetbtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
resetbtn.addEventListener('click', reset);

const DELAY_BETWEEN_SWAPS = 25;

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

let cancelLast = () => {};

let count = 0;
let amount = 100;

// create div that has custom attribute value, unique style tag, default bar style and append.
function generateBar() {
  // generate div
  let bar = document.createElement('div');
  // keep track of the total amount of bars
  count++;
  // assign random number 0-100 and setAttribute to the div
  let temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
  // create custom attribute that holds its value
  bar.setAttribute('value', temp);
  // create unique style tag with height as a percentage based on Attribute
  let barHeight = document.createElement('style');
  barHeight.innerHTML = `.barHeight${count} {height: ${temp}%;}`;
  // add that unique style to the DOM
  sortDisplay.appendChild(barHeight);
  // now add that unique style to the div
  bar.classList.add(`barHeight${count}`);
  // use standard style from css as well
  bar.classList.add('sortBar');
  // now add that div to the DOM
  sortDisplay.appendChild(bar);
}

// clear container div and regenerate
function reset() {
  cancelLast();
  // clear all data within the container
  sortDisplay.innerHTML = '';
  // reset the count
  count = 0;
  // generate k bars
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    generateBar();
  }
}

// when page is loaded reset
reset(amount);

// swap elements within the DOM
function swapElements(obj1, obj2) {
  // create marker element and insert it above where obj1 is
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  obj1.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, obj1);
  // move obj1 to right before obj2
  obj2.parentNode.insertBefore(obj1, obj2);
  // move obj2 to right before where obj1 used to be
  temp.parentNode.insertBefore(obj2, temp);
  // remove temporary marker node
  temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
}

// sort the divs within the DOM
async function sort(cancellationChecker) {
  for (let i = 1; i < amount; i++) {
    let j = i;
    for (j; j > 0; j--) {
      if (cancellationChecker()) return;
      if (+document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j].getAttribute('value') < +document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j-1].getAttribute('value')) {
        swapElements(document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j], document.querySelectorAll('.sortBar')[j-1]);
        await delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_SWAPS);
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function btnSort() {
  let cancelled = false;
  cancelLast();
  cancelLast = () => cancelled = true;
  sort(() => cancelled);
}

// Button to run the sort function
button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.addEventListener('click', btnSort);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sortDisplay {
  background-color: #305c50;
  background-image: linear-gradient(28deg, #305c50 0%, #6ab19e 70%, #82d8a6 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 25px;
}

.btn-container button {
  padding: 25px;
}

.sortBar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #0007;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="reset">reset</button>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>

<div id="sortDisplay"class="sortDisplay"></div>
```